# I want to add to the Record Collection challenge from freeCodeCamp, but I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Ok, so I went through the Record Collection tutorial and have a pretty solid understanding of the original challenge. However, I want my function to be able to add a new ID to the collection if it doesn't already exist. I've tried so many variations, and I can't figure out how to do that (noob -_-). I know this isn't necessary, but I think this will help with my overall understanding of objects and arrays anyway.

Code below is my latest attempt. The first if statement is my add-on. Should I be running an if statement with .hasOwnProperty first? Idk. Please explain in dummy terms. :)

```
var collection = {
    2548: {
        album: "Slippery When Wet",
        artist: "Bon Jovi",
        tracks: [
            "Let It Rock",
            "You Give Love a Bad Name"
        ]
    },
    2468: {
        album: "1999",
        artist: "Prince",
        tracks: [
            "1999",
            "Little Red Corvette"
        ]
    },
    1245: {
        artist: "Robert Palmer",
        tracks: []
    },
    5439: {
        album: "ABBA Gold"
    }
};

function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {

// If the id is not blank and the prop is not blank,
    if (id !== "" && prop !== "") {

// then create the new id name and push the property onto it.
        collection.id = [];
        collection[id].push(prop);
    }

//If the property is equal to "tracks" and the tracks value isn't empty,
    else if (value !== "" && prop === "tracks") {

//update or set the value for the property.
        collection[id][prop].tracks;

//If the specificied id doesn't have the property tracks,
    } else if (!collection[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks")) {

//then add the property tracks and push in the track's name value       
        collection[id].tracks = [];
        collection[id].tracks.push(value);

//Otherwise delete the id entirely.
    } else {

    delete collection[id][prop];
    }

    return collection;
}

updateRecords(2005, "tracks", "check on it");
```

Comment: “update or set the value for the property” should result in tracks referencing the supplied value, just as “ add the property tracks and push in the track's name value ” (so common code) ?

Comment: That's what I thought and tried, but I'm having a syntax issue I guess. Would you put: `if (!collection.hasOwnProperty(id))`? I'm starting to get lost with the brackets vs. dot notation although I do have notes for it in my editor. What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are trying to make sure a record doesn't exist before adding it to a collection, the easiest way to do it is to use something like `Array.find`.

The below code only checks the `id` field to see if it already exists. In your scenario, you may want to check other properties, so your `.find` will have some extra checks.

Example:

```js
const records = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Test1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Test2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Test3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'Test4' },
];

const addRecord = (record) => {
  if (record) {
    const existingRecord = records.find(r => r.id === record.id);
    if (existingRecord) { return `Record ${record.id} already exists`; }
    records.push(record);
    return records;
  }
  return 'Record cannot be falsy';
}

console.log(addRecord({ id: 5, name: 'Test5' })); // Adds record
console.log(addRecord({ id: 1, name: 'Test123123123 doesnt matter' })); // Record already exists
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Example with `object` collection instead of `array` of `objects`

```js
let records = {
  1: { name: 'Test1' },
  2: { name: 'Test2' },
  3: { name: 'Test3' },
  4: { name: 'Test4' }
};

const findRecord = (recordId) => {
  for(const key in records) {
    if (+key === recordId) return records[key];
  }
  return null;
};

const addRecord = (id, name) => {
  if (id && name) {
    const recordExists = findRecord(id);
    if (recordExists) return `Record ${id} already exists`;
    records[id] = { name };
    return records;
  }
  return 'Record cannot be falsy';
};

console.log(addRecord(5, 'Test5')); // Adds record
console.log(addRecord(1, 'blag asdfsdafafds')); // Already exists
```

Comment: So, using the original format wouldn't necessarily be the best way to go about it. I'm still learning, and I'll definitely read up on your suggestion more. Thanks!

Comment: You can, but it's much more "wordy" and harder to read. There are plenty of array methods out there that make searching for something existing very easy. Check out `Array.find`, `Array.filter`, `Array.includes`, etc... Lots of helpful methods out there. Make sure to upvote/mark as answer if this helps!

Comment: Also, just saw that you're working with an object and not an array. I'll update my answer

Comment: Hold on, explain... I'm working with an object with nested arrays.

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to do it with objects. You can use the first example (with `Array.find`) to get after your nested arrays.

Answer (score -2):

Another way to do it:

```js
let records = {
    1: { name: 'Test1' },
    2: { name: 'Test2' },
    3: { name: 'Test3' },
    4: { name: 'Test4' }
}

const addRecord = (id, name) => {
    if (!id || !name) {
        return 'Id and name must be defined'
    }

    const exists = Object.keys(records).some(recordId => +recordId === id)

    if (exists) {
        return `${id} already exists`
    }

    records[id] = { name }

    return records
}

console.log(addRecord(5, 'Test5')) // Adds record
console.log(addRecord(1, 'blag asdfsdafafds')) // Already exists
```